# Give commands to print the lines containing the word “Unix” or “unix” in aa.txt file. Try to use grep, awk and sed command (3 different commands)

Tags: awk, sed, grep

like how do I pick them? both "Unix" and 'unix'

in my opinion

1. using awk

   ```
   $ awk ~"Unix|unix" {print $0}.aa.txt
   ```
2. using grep
   have no clue
3. using sed

   ```
   $ sed "/Unix/p" aa.txt | "/unix/p" aa.txt
   ```

i think these all wrong

so plz answer me ... I have NO clue..

Comment: You can find full manuals for the GNU versions of awk and sed at https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html and https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html - they contain basic tutorials and examples.  (these manuals may also be installed on your system as Texinfo documents - try `info awk` or `info sed`. or use `pinfo` instead of `info`).  Also google for 'awk tutorial' or 'sed tutorial'.

Comment: Should a line containing `unixware` or `immunix` or `plunixish` be printed? How about `UNIX`?

Answer (score 2):

A regular expression matching both the string `Unix` and `unix` would be `[Uu]nix`, where `[Uu]` matches one of `U` or `u`.

You would use the three tools like the following to pull out all the lines that matches this expression:

- `awk '/[Uu]nix/' file`

  This is an `awk` program in "short form" that uses the fact that `awk` prints the current record (line) if the given condition matches.  The "long-hand" variation, with all uneccessary bits of code included, would look like `awk '$0 ~ /[Uu]nix/ { print $0 }' file`.
- `grep '[Uu]nix' file`

  The `grep` utility simply extracts the lines matching the given expression.
- `sed -n '/[Uu]nix/p' file`

  This `sed` command turns off (with `-n`) the default printing of each line.  It then explicitly prints only the lines matching the given expression.

  Using `sed`, you could also opt for *deleting* the lines we don't want to see and use the default printing of each line to output the ones left behind:  `sed '/[Uu]nix/!d' file`

Out of `awk`, `grep` and `sed`,  the `grep` utility is the most natural fit for the task of extracting lines matching a particular expression.  You would most often use `awk` for tasks requiring more processing or summarizing, and `sed` for single line modifications with little or no need for keeping state (but all three tools overlap in their applications).

Comment: then how do I print them?

Comment: @dodoriri  "Print"? You mean, "on paper"?

Comment: nahh like sed'/pattern/p' file <- in this case the latter 'p' right after the slash!

Comment: `grep -i unix file` works too...

Comment: @albertovar Yes, but that would also match `uNIX`, which the question did not ask for.

Comment: @dodoriri All the commands that I have shown prints the result to the terminal if you run them on a file called `file`.  If you have issues running any of them, let me know what seems to go wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The trickier part of the question is "match the *word* Unix or unix"

With the input file

```
$ cat -n file
     1  how do I pick them? both "Unix" and 'unix'
     2  Could be just Unix
     3  or just
     4  unix at the start of line
     5  do not match unixy or munix
```

We should match lines 1, 2 and 4, but not line 5 because "unix" does not appear "as a word".

Also demonstrating the way these tools have builtin facilities to do case insensitive matching.

1. grep

   ```bsh
   $ grep -i unix file
   how do I pick them? both "Unix" and 'unix'
   Could be just Unix
   unix at the start of line
   do not match unixy or munix
   ```

   now add the `-w` ("whole word") option:

   ```bsh
   $ grep -i -w unix file
   how do I pick them? both "Unix" and 'unix'
   Could be just Unix
   unix at the start of line
   ```
2. GNU sed

   ```bsh
   $ gsed -n '/unix/I p' file
   how do I pick them? both "Unix" and 'unix'
   Could be just Unix
   unix at the start of line
   do not match unixy or munix
   ```

   Now add the GNU regexp word boundary markers

   ```bsh
   $ gsed -n '/\<unix\>/I p' file
   how do I pick them? both "Unix" and 'unix'
   Could be just Unix
   unix at the start of line
   ```

   (I'm on a Mac with GNU sed installed as `gsed` via Homebrew)
3. GNU awk

   ```bsh
   $ gawk -v IGNORECASE=1 '/unix/' file
   how do I pick them? both "Unix" and 'unix'
   Could be just Unix
   unix at the start of line
   do not match unixy or munix
   ```

   ```bsh
   $ gawk -v IGNORECASE=1 '/\<unix\>/' file
   how do I pick them? both "Unix" and 'unix'
   Could be just Unix
   unix at the start of line
   ```
4. non-GNU tools: for example the default awk and sed on a Mac

   These tools do not use GNU regexes and do not have the handy `\<` `\>` word boundaries. Neither is the case insensitive matching available. The result is not so pretty.

   ```bsh
   /usr/bin/sed -En '/(^|[^_[:alnum:]])[Uu]nix($|[^_[:alnum:]])/ p' file
   /usr/bin/awk 'tolower($0) ~ /(^|[^_[:alnum:]])unix($|[^_[:alnum:]])/' file
   /usr/bin/awk -F'[^[:alpha:]]+' '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if (tolower($i) == "unix") {print; next}}' file
   ```